# Como recuperar el resultado de un web service en java

Tags: java, xml, webservice, arraylist

Consumo un web service que me retorna los datos de una persona, pero en algunos casos me retorna varios datos, es decir en un ArrayList. He implementado un componente en Java para recuperar esos datos y los coloco en un bean llamado RespuestaPersona pero cuando retorna en un arraylist se cae indica: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.mi.ws.RespuestaPersona

he intentando cambiar recuperándolo en un List, pero cuando me trae varios datos esta ok, pero cuando me trae solo un dato sale otro mensaje: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mi.ws.RespuestaPersona cannot be cast to java.util.List

[image: El xml del ws me retorna en un arraylist]

[image: Y cuando es un dato me retorna en clase Respuesta Persona]

Me podrían ayudar con este problema que tengo. Como debo recuperar en java en cualquiera de los 2 casos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, ésto es un cliente generado a partir de un WSDL?

Comment: Por favor, en vez de contarnos lo que intentas y falla, muéstranos lo que intentas (el código) y las excepciones que encuentras.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.mi.ws.RespuestaPersona` tienes que usar el mismo formato de lista, es decir el que viene el `servicioWSDL.jar` o del cual lo este obteniendo y el error es por que usas el `(ArrayList) lista` y publica tu código, para saber que es lo que hace realmente